# Sort DataList::get using an array of IDs

Tags: silverstripe

I'm doing a DataList::get() with a where clause using an array containing some IDs.

```
$result = DataList::get('MyObject')->where('ID IN(' .implode(',',$idArr). ')');
```

My array looks like

```
array
  0 => string '1'
  1 => string '12'
  2 => string '2'
  3 => string '11'
```

I want the result of the DataList:get() to be sorted/ordered in the same order of $idArr. I tried

```
$masteries = Mastery::get()->where('ID IN(' .implode(',',$idArr). ')')->sort('ID', implode(',',$idArr));
```

but that didn't work. Is there a way to do this using DataList or would I have to do a custom query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$masteries = Mastery::get()
    ->where('ID IN(' . implode(',',$idArr) . ')')
    ->sort('field(ID,' . implode(',',$idArr) . ') ASC');
```

Comment: Sweet. On a side note, 'field' is a mysql thing, so if you're writing unit tests for that piece of code, and rely on sqlite3 as an adapter for the database, this query will fail miserably.

Comment: this is not safe because it is using a where clause (and sort) that is assuming the data is clean.  The silverstripe ORM allows you to say ->filter('ID',$idArr) which is much more concise but also will filter the $idArr

Answer (score 7):

For completeness it should be noted that the OP asked about a way to do this with `DataList` so the ORM way of writing this query (complete with standard sort behaviour) would be:

```
$masteries = Mastery::get()
    ->filter(array('ID' => $idArr))
    ->sort('ID', 'ASC'); // See the docblock for DataList::sort()
```

Comment: this is much better as it is safe, however no need for an array when passing one filter value

Comment: @Barry for sure. In my defence I thought I was going to use more than one filter param, but removed it and kept the array :-)